# Why is my file-reading function only reading odd-numbered lines?

Tags: python

I have a text file containing all integers from 0 to 99, inclusive:

```
0
1
2
3
[...]
98
99
```

And I've written the following code to try and print out each line:

```py
f = open('number_list.txt', 'r')
for x in f:
    r = f.readline()
    r2 = r.rstrip('\n')
    print(r2)
```

But for some reason it only prints every second number:

```
1
3
5
[...]
97
99
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code or output; paste it as text instead.

Comment: The code you provided and the code in the screenshot are different!

Comment: @Eeshaan Well, one is the code with which they wrote the file, and the other is the code that opens it and tries to print each line. But yes, that could be more clearly explained.

Comment: Please copy-paste your code. and read how to create an [mre]

Comment: sorry, i just edited it. its should make more sense now.

Comment: @MINO Please copy-paste your code!

Comment: @MINO I did it for you. but please do it yourself next time.

Comment: @ppwater ok thanks mate, i am new here so i have no idea about it . but will do next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for x in f:` already iterates through each line of your file. So by doing:

```
for x in f:
    r = f.readline()
```

you're reading two lines at a time (hence the odd numbers).
Just get rid of the call to readline(), and use `x` as your line.

Answer (score 2):

You're reading lines from the file in two different ways.

`for x in f` reads a line from the file once per iteration.

`readline()` also reads a line from the file.

You're not printing the lines from the `for` loop;  you're only printing the lines from `readline()`.

So you're reading every line, but you're only only printing every other line.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're not using the `x` variable at all, which contain the current line. Instead of using it, you're consuming the next line by doing `r = f.readline()`:

```py
f = open("number_list.txt", "r")
for x in f:
    print(x) <--- use x instead
```